Better way to run this python (matplotlib) code for plotting and saving images
I have the following code that reads data from a csv, plots it and then saves the plot as images. The csv file has x and y values in columns index 0 and 1 and also has RGB values for color in column index 18 through 21. Through this code I am able to read the x and y values at any row and plot them as a line connected to the previous x and y values in a specific color. What I get in the end is a series of images where my csv x and y values are being plotted sequentially. The issue is that this code takes a really long time to execute for csv files with about 5,000 rows. For csv files with more than 10,000 rows my system runs out of memory soon and the code fails. Any recommendations on how to make it better?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import os

csv_file_path = "my_data.csv"
output_dir = "my_dir"

try:
    with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        next(reader)  # Skip the header

        x = []
        y = []
        colors = []

        # Create the figure and axes only once
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=300)

        # Set axis limits and aspect ratio
        ax.set_xlim(0, 960*2)
        ax.set_ylim(-960*2, 0)
        ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
        ax.axis('off')

        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            x.append(float(row[0]))
            y.append(-float(row[1]))  # y-coordinate needs to be inverted for plotting
            rgb = tuple(float(val)/255.0 for val in row[18:21])
            colors.append(rgb)

            # Plot each line segment with its color
            if i > 0:  # Start plotting from the second point
                ax.plot(x[i-1:i+1], y[i-1:i+1], linewidth=0.5, color=colors[i-1]) 

            # Save the figure
            frame_filename = os.path.join(output_dir, f"frame_{i:06d}.png")
            plt.savefig(frame_filename, transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)

        plt.close(fig)  # Close the figure after the loop

    print(f"Frames saved in the directory: {output_dir}")

except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"Error: File not found at {file_path}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


Try matplotlib.use('Agg') to disable GUI and might help with memory usage. I have no clue though. 10000*21 doubles would only takes about 1MB, and there is only one figure and one axis object present, the only suspicious target is the 10000 line segments. Though I don't think it's an issue, you can also try the LineCollection official example, which may or may not help.

You keep over-drawing the same lines 10,000 times.  See the set_xdata and set_ydata methods

Thanks. Will check these suggestions out.
